# Is gradle necessary for building Cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

Ever since I updated Cordova and it installed gradle I've not been able to build my android apps that were previously working. I've just noticed that I get an error when trying to run the apps in an android emulator (which previously worked) related to gradle

```
Waiting for emulator...  
Booting up emulator (this may take a while).......................BOOT COMPLETE  
Running: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true  
Unzipping /home/lyndon/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to /home/lyndon/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)  
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)  
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)  
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)  
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)  
... 3 more  

/home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;  
                      ^  
Error code 1 for command: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true  
Error: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1  
at ChildProcess.whenDone   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)  
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)  
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)  
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Is gradle necessary for building android app with cordova can I get rid of it or is there some other way of fixing this problem? thanks!

Comment: I think you have to try by removing and adding android platform again this may resolve your problem..

Comment: Thanks I already tried removing the android platform then adding it again but it didn't work. When I do try to add the android platform there is this error  Fetching from npm failed: EACCES, mkdir '/home/lyndon/tmp/npm-18951-farlzl0v'

Comment: That's a permissions error, so do verify your permissions are set correctly.

Comment: I think Huey is right, you have to try excute command with super user...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to run the command without sudo? It seems unnecessary to have to set global environment variables like ANDROID_HOME for these purposes.